# Text of html select aligned at bottom in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

i applied

```
select{
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

to a html select box. Every Browser except this IE8 aligns the text inside the select box vertically centered (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llpx.png)). I have no idead what to do to fix that.
I already read a lot of answer to similiar problems here at stackoverflow and played with box-sizing and padding properties but without success.!

[here is what the errorneous layout in IE8 looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llpx.png)

Comment: do you have a link to a website?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, what I have found is that if you only apply `padding` to give the height and vertical alignment of just the select element you can achieve a cross-browser solution, even for the likes of IE8, using only `padding`:

Please see my [pen](http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/OPLEgx)

As Codepen does not support IE8 please export my pen as a zip and view the file locally either emulating IE8 or using a genuine installation of IE8 somewhere.

or just copy my code below and create your own .html file

**HTML**

```
<select name='options'>
  <option value='option-1'>Option 1 that could be fairly long</option>
  <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply conditional CSS styling targetting IE8 browser only.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="styles/IE8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Seems to me the issue can be resolved by fiddling with `line-height` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<div class="styled-select">
<select>
  <option>Here is the first option</option>
  <option>The second option</option>
</select>
</div>

.styled-select select {
background: transparent;
width: 268px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
height: 34px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help. the problem that letters like "qpfgjy" are cut-off at the bottom still exists.
and